# pytest issues with a session scoped fixture and asyncio

Tags: python, pytest, python-asyncio, semaphore, pytest-xdist

I have multiple test files, each has an async fixture that looks like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
def event_loop(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()


@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
async def some_fixture():
    return await make_fixture()
```

I'm using xdist for parallelization. In addition I have this decorator:

```
@toolz.curry
def throttle(limit, f):
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(limit)

    @functools.wraps(f)
    async def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        async with semaphore:
            return await f(*args, **kwargs)

    return wrapped
```

and I have a function uses it:

```
@throttle(10)
def f():
    ...
```

Now `f` is being called from multiple test files, and I'm getting an exception telling me that I can't use the semaphore from different event loops.

I tried moving to a session-level event loop fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def event_loop(request):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop_policy().new_event_loop()
    yield loop
    loop.close()
```

But this only gave me:

> ScopeMismatch: You tried to access the 'function' scoped fixture 'event_loop' with a 'module' scoped request object, involved factories

Is it even possible to have xdist + async fixture + semaphore working together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually got it to work using the following `conftest.py`:

```py
import asyncio

import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def event_loop():
    return asyncio.get_event_loop()
```

Comment: This worked for me, but it seems a bug with pytest-asyncio

Comment: It's not a bug, the pytest-asyncio event_loop fixture by default is scoped to "function", so you get a new event_loop for each test function. Therefore, it's not possible for another async fixture to live for the entire session as this would span multiple different event loops. You need to override the event_loop fixture with the scope you need, as shown in Uri's answer.

See "Fixtures" under https://pypi.org/project/pytest-asyncio/

Comment: This is not good and will break in future versions of python, if it doesn't already break tests.  Your tests will run in a different event loop to the one returned by this fixture.  `get_event_loop` is going away in a future version of python anyway, so this will already generate warnings.